# Was the doctrine of the rapture rediscovered by the Plymouth Brethern?

Tags: church-history, eschatology, rapture, premillennialism

Multiple times I heard the assertion that the *doctrine of the rapture* was rediscovered by [John Darby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Nelson_Darby) and/or the [Plymouth Brethren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plymouth_Brethren), allegedly after it had been lost for approximately 1500 years.

Yet, this assertion was never based with any source.

So, is it true that the doctrine of the rapture (as it was taught by the Plymouth Brethren) was indeed rediscovered by them?

Comment: Welcome!  This question (or one very similar to it) [has already been asked](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/321/21576), so this one may be closed as a duplicate.  I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).